# How can i fix this error it says the list index is out of range?

Tags: python

I'm wondering why this error keeps showing. I did all my best that I could. I just want to print my name using an asterisk. Can you please help me? PS. Im a beginner.
The error is line 55, in  :

```
print(print_A[i][j], end=" ")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

here's my full code

```
str1 = "MARC"
print_M = [[" " for i in range(7)] for j in range(7)]
print_A = [[" " for i in range(7)] for j in range(5)]
print_R = [[" " for i in range(7)] for j in range(5)]
print_C = [[" " for i in range(7)] for j in range(5)]

# code for M
for row in range(7):
for col in range(7):
    if (col == 0 or col == 6) or (row == col and col < 4) or (row + 
col == 6 and col > 3):
        print("* ", end="")
    else:
        print("  ", end="")
print()

# for A
str1 = ""
for row in range(7):
for col in range(5):
    if ((col == 0 or col == 4) and row != 0) or ((row == 0 or row == 
3) and (col > 0 and col < 4)):
        str1 = str1 + "*"
    else:
        str1 = str1 + " "
str1 = str1 + "\n"
print(str1)

# for R
for row in range(7):
for col in range(5):
    if col == 0 or (col == 4 and (row != 0 and row != 3)) or ((row == 
0 or row == 3) and (0 < col < 4)):
        print("*", end="")
    else:
        print(end=" ")
print()
# for C
for row in range(7):
for col in range(5):
    if (col == 0) or ((row == 0 or row == 6) and (col > 0)):
        print("*", end="")
    else:
        print(end="")
print()

for i in range(7):
for j in range(7):
    print(print_M[i][j], end=" ")
print(end="  ")
for j in range(5):
    print(print_A[i][j], end=" ")
print(end="  ")
for j in range(5):
    print(print_R[i][j], end=" ")
print(end="  ")
for j in range(5):
    print(print_C[i][j], end=" ")
print()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  There is no need to dump 50 lines of code to illustrate your problem.  Also note that your posted code fails to run; please verify that it really does reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh okay im sorry

Comment: Correct the indents plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a list containing 5 elements, each of which is a 7-item list (in fact the same one each time).

```
print_A = [[" " for i in range(7)] for j in range(5)]
```

You can do (up to):

```
print_A[4][6]
```

but it is the wrong shape to do:

```
print_A[6][4]
```

Here (with assumptions about the indentation you intended, because what you posted is not valid) is how you are looping over it:

```
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(5):
        print(print_A[i][j], end=" ")
```

So you are trying to look up at indices that are out of range for this (rectangular) shape -- the `print_A[i]` is failing when `i` is 6 (so the `[j]` lookup is not reached).

You probably meant:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(7):
        print(print_A[i][j], end=" ")
```

(or to swap `i` and `j` loops, depending which loop variable you intended for each of the inner and outer loops).

Similarly for `print_R` and `print_C`.  The `print_M` is okay because it is square shape.

Answer (score 0):

You have your subscripts switched.  The letters ARC are all 5x7 character maps, but your print loops are:

```
for i in range(7):
    ...
    for j in range(5):
        print(print_A[i][j], end=" ")
    print(end="  ")
```

You cannot run `i` past a value of 4, since that dimension is only 5 long.

Switch `i` and `j`, either in loop range or subscript order.